# Where can I find a measure-theoretic statement of the Von Neumann-Morgenstern axioms?

Tags: self-study, references, decision-theory, measure-theory

Most of the discussion of the Von Neumann-Morgenstern axioms I have seen isn't fully formal - in fact, a lot of it only applies to finite probability spaces. Where can I find a more general discussion, discussing preference orderings on a general space and whether a utility function exists? Or is there a reason that these axioms are generally not phrased in terms of measure theory I don't see - perhaps they don't have to be for some reason?